# Как сохранять в sessionStorage несколько значений по 1 ключу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Как сохранять в sessionStorage несколько значений по 1 ключу

```
const nameBrands = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(subsProductsBrandPopupKey));
    const name = [brand.name];
    if (!nameBrands) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(subsProductsBrandPopupKey, JSON.stringify(name));
    }
    const findName = nameBrands.find((item: string) => (item === brand.name));
    if (findName) {
      sendPopupBrandsLikesEvent('show');
      setIsOpenPopup(true);
    } else {
      nameBrands.push(brand.name);
      sessionStorage.setItem(subsProductsBrandPopupKey, JSON.stringify(nameBrands));
    }


sessionStorage.getItem(subsProductsBrandPopupKey)
```

вот здесь выдает ошибку
TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: `subsProductsBrandPopupKey` может быть `null`, откуда у вас эта переменная?

Comment: из файла констаты 
export const subsProductsBrandPopupKey = 'subsProductsBrandPopup';

Comment: `torage.getItem(key: string): string | null` а JSON.parse принимает только string. Перед тем как пихать туда данные надо проверить на null

Comment: @АлександрРогонов можешь пример написать, потому что делаю как ты указал, у меня ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Не до конца понятно, что вы тут делаете.

```
const nameBrands = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(subsProductsBrandPopupKey));
```

Насколько я вижу, проблема в этой строчке. sessionStorage.getItem возвращает string | null а JSON.parse принимает только string.

Если по простому, то вот такая конструкция должна вас спасти.

```
const nameBrands = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(subsProductsBrandPopupKey) || '[]');
```